# Trouble with Regular Expression and Ampersand

Tags: c#, asp.net, expression

I'm having a bit of trouble with regex's (C#, ASP.NET), and I'm pretty sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.  My task is to bind a dynamically created gridview to a datasource, and then iterate through a column in the grid, looking for the string "A&I".  An example of what the data in the cell (in template column) looks like is:

```
Name: John Doe
Phone: 555-123-1234
Email: john.doe@url.com
Dept: DHS-A&I-MRB
```

Here's the code I'm using to find the string value:

```
foreach(GridViewRow gvrow in gv.Rows)
{
   Match m = Regex.Match(gvrow.Cells[6].Text,"A&I");

   if(m.Success)
   {
      gvrow.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   }
}
```

I'm not having any luck with any of these variations:
"A&I"
"[A][&][I]"

But when I strictly user "&", the row does turn red.  Any suggestions?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Regex looks fine to me. I suspect the text to perhaps be encoded like:

```
A&amp;I
```

on the input.

You could also do `gvrow.Cells[6].Text.Contains("A&I")` instead of regex. Or `gvrow.Cells[6].Text.Contains("A&amp;I")` if I'm right with the encoding issue.

string.Contains is also faster than Regex.

You could also `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` on the text before checking for the occurance of A&I.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used "A&amp;I" and it worked.  Also, BIG thanks for the "contains" suggestion -- I didn't know about it until you told me!

Answer (score 1):

Both of these match successfully:

```
Match m = Regex.Match("DHS-A&I-MRB", "A&I");
Match m0 = Regex.Match("DHS-A&I-MRB", @"A\&I");

Debug.WriteLine("m.Success = " + m.Success.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine("m0.Success = " + m0.Success.ToString());
```

Output:

```
m.Success = True
m0.Success = True
```

Perhaps the problem is elsewhere (possibly the wrong Cells index)?

Comment: I used that exact example, and they tested true. However, when testing the gridview output, they would fail. I think the problem is the encoding -- I just tested "A&amp;I" and it worked. (By the way, I've been guilty of the wrong column index before...so I quadruple checked before posting here ;) Thanks for the suggestion, though. )